# Databricks RemoteFileChangedException

Tags: amazon-s3, hadoop, pyspark, databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

I want to create a dataframe by reading S3 folder which is continuously updated by another stream. (Approximately, 1 file per second)

```
df = spark.read.format("json").load(s3_path)
display(df)
```

While using the **no isolation shared** cluster, it fails with the below error.

> Caused by: com.databricks.common.filesystem.InconsistentReadException: The file might have been updated during query execution. Ensure that no pipeline updates existing files during query execution and try again.

> Caused by: shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.RemoteFileChangedException: open `s3a://xxxxx/year=2023/month=09/day=25/xxx@xxx.xx': Change reported by S3 during open at position 0. File s3a://xxxxx/year=2023/month=09/day=25/xxx@xxx.xx at given modTime (1695657855000) was unavailable, null

It looks like it is complaining about a file that has been changed while it tries to read.

I have tried to change `fs.s3a.change.detection.mode` to `none`.
In the documentation, it says `none` should not complain when there is a change on file.
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html

In cluster configuration UI, I set `spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.change.detection.mode none`
But it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **Databricks Runtime Version: 13.3 LTS**, a new feature has been introduced to proactively detect and raise an error if a file has been modified between the query planning phase and its execution.

https://docs.databricks.com/en/release-notes/runtime/13.3lts.html#databricks-runtime-returns-an-error-if-a-file-is-modified-between-query-planning-and-invocation

If you switch your cluster to **Databricks Runtime Version: 12.2 LTS**, it should work fine.